# How to get a very high precision for a too large number and for a too small number in Java?

Tags: java, precision, biginteger, bigdecimal, largenumber

I am going to make calculations that contain either large or small numbers and result in either a very large or a very small number.

What I am care about now is **how to get things go as precise as possible**.

When I try this calculation on Google calculator
1000^10 = 1e+30
Which can be read as 1000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000

When I try the same calculations using BigDecimal, I got a different result!

```
  BigDecimal bigNumber = new BigDecimal(Math.pow(1000, 10));
  System.out.println(bigNumber);
```

1000,000,000,000,000,019,884,624,838,656

I am happy that it gives me the full range of numbers without using the scientific notation but it gives some extra rubbish numbers at the end.

Note that I am not confined to BigDecimal. I am care about precision in anyway.

So, **How to get a very high precision for a too large number and for a too small number in Java?**

Comment: You didn't 'try the same calculations using `BigDecimal.`' You did the same calculations in floating-point and *then* converted the *result* to `BigDecimal`.

Comment: You need to use BigDecimal.  Doing the calculation in `double` and converting it to BigDecimal doesn't magically give it more precision.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using `BigDecimal` and doing calculation in `double` is the same as not using `BigDecimal` at all.

Use `BigDecimal` to do calculations:

```
BigDecimal bigNumber = new BigDecimal(1000).pow(10);
System.out.println(bigNumber);
```